# List of fields that can be updated through real-time updates functionality?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time

Can somebody create (or link to) a complete list of updatable fields through the [real-time updates](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "*updatable*" fields? fields that you can subscribe to? and if yes, aren't these fields already highlighted in the document you linked to above?

Comment: Sorry ... I posted the question quite in a rush. The thing is that not all the fields or connections are working. I already posted an answer Juicy Scripter that I have trouble with submitting to some fields/connections updates (like user middle_name, language etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [Real-time Updates](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) (which you refer in question) have list of those fields and connections (this is by far the most complete list available right now):

> - [`user`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user) – Get notifications about particular fields and connections corresponding to user nodes in the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/).
> - [`permissions`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) – Get notifications when your users change the permissions they afford your applications. The available permissions are listed in the scope table in the [permissions API reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).
> - [`page`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page) - Get notifications when pages that have installed your application as a Tab change their public properties. Note that the page topic is only used for subscribing to changes to public attributes of the page (like name, category, picture etc). This is the same information that is returned by the Graph API call
>     `https://graph.facebook.com/<PAGE_ID>`.
>
> **Note:** Not all properties and connections of the user object can be subscribed to.
>
> You can subscribe to all of the User object properties except verified.
>
> Here are the list of User connections to which you can subscribe: feed, friends, activities, interests, music, books, movies, television, likes, checkins.
>
> You can't subscribe to these User connections yet: home, tagged, posts, photos, albums, videos, groups, notes, events, inbox, outbox, updates, accounts.

The documentation is also states that plans to add more properties in future. So it's recommended to check it periodically...

Comment: The thing is that not all the fields listed there work. Neither do the connections. For ex.: for middle_name I get '(#100) "middle_name" is an invalid field name'. I get the same for 'publish_stream' permission and the list could go on.

Comment: @alex, if the documentation says a field should work and it doesn't, then you should file a bug at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs if you think the API is in error, or click the link at the bottom of the documentation page if you think that the documentation is in error.